# Can A matrix with integers have determinant 3

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem:If the entries of both $A$ and $A^{−1}$ are integers, is it possible that $detA = 3$? Hint: what is $det(A)det(A^{−1})$?

attempt:I know $det(A)det(A^{−1})=1$

And since $detA=3$ would that imply $det(A^{−1})=\frac{1}{3}$?

And so it is not possible that $detA=3$?

Would this mean that $A^{-1}$ does not have integer entries?

Comment: You know the operations involved in computing the determinant.  If you apply those operations to integers, can the result be a fraction?

Comment: Yes, if a matrix has integer entries, its determinant must be an integer,  and if $\ A\ $ and $\ A^{-1}\ $ both have integer entries then their determinants must either both be $\ +1\ $ or both be $\ -1\ $.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The only way that a matrix of inegers can have an inverse that also consists entirely of integers is for the matrix and its inverse both to have determinant 1 or both to have detrminant -1.

Comment: I am struggling to understand why $det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{3}$ implies some of the entries are not integers.Can you help explain?

Comment: If you add and multiply integers you get integers. If the $\det$ is not an integer then at least one entry must not be an integer.